Simple Notation to Say "A combination of" components?
I would like to delve into writing in a more scientific way to define my problems. My though is that it will help me see more similarities between problems faster.

Question
Hence, I would like to know how to write "a combination of" in a theoretical computer science way or mathematical way?

Idea:



Let say we have a software component (library, microservice, engine etc.) that is able to generate an output (scalar values, vectors, picture etc.). Combining two components may result in another component that incorporates a series of components, which are connected. For simplicity, we don't focus on the connections.


Example:


Lets make it simple: I have a component c_1 that is a microservice
that calculates a function f(x) with input vector v=(x,y). The second
component c_2 that calculates a distance d(v1, v2),
with v1 and v2 being vectors of the from v=(x,y). Now, we stretch it a
bit further and say we have more components c_3, c_4 etc. doing something
different.

I would write "a combination of" in a more general view in such a way:

Let be C a software component with an input I and output O, where I =
{all well defined inputs} and O = {all well defined outputs}. Thus, an
component C(I) = O_I. A component C can be divided into sub-components
C_sub, where each sub-component is either a single component C or a
combination of sub-components. This is symbolized as C(I) = C_sub(I) =
O_I, with C = C_sub or C(I) = C_sub1 AND C_sub2 AND C_sub3 AND ... AND
C_sub3 = O_(I).

or could I write + instead of AND?

A component C can be divided into sub-components
C_sub, where each sub-component is either a single component C or a
combination of sub-components. This is symbolized as C(I) = C_sub(I) =
O_I, with C = C_sub or C(I) = C_sub1 + C_sub2 + C_sub3 +... +
C_sub3 = O_(I).

What are your suggestions and maybe sources and books you can recommend?

You should define what kind of mathematical objects you're dealing with before you worry about syntax. You might want to look at Seven sketches in compositionality and more generally the fields of category theory and applied category theory.

@NaïmFavier I thank you for the recommendation! Already the first part with the simple systems is an deep insight into formalization for me!
